# How can I combine AUC and averaged 11-point precision/recall?

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, evaluation, collective-intelligence

I am evaluating a recommender and I have ROC curves and Precision-Recall curves. When I change some parameters the ROC and PR curves change a little bit differently. Sometimes the ROC curve looks better than the PR curve, or the other way around. Therefore I want both curves. I can boil down the ROC Curve to AUC, and since I have a 11-point PR curve I can take the mean over the 11 points to get a single number.

Can I combine these measures somehow to one number? And is this something that people do or is that unnecessary?

Is the fact that the ROC looks better than the PR just a subjective thing because I am not good at intrepreting the curves, or is it valid that one can be better than the other? (They are not completely different, but it´s still noticable I think)

EDIT:
Basically I don´t want to show tons of plots, I want a table of numbers. Would you combine these numbers in one table? Or make a table for each measure?

Answer (score 1):

What people do most in common systems is to use the AUC (area under the ROC curve) or the F-Measure as summary metrics. But how you are dealing with recommender systems, until what i know they like to see the precision and recall curves (like [these](http://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/prroc2.jpg&imgrefurl=http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/roc.html&h=559&w=720&sz=53&tbnid=f8U246eE8LMfEM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=116&zoom=1&usg=__A4_JMVCetIHxTmSrmGYmfxBOZQY=&docid=Rn8b8fH9qyEGUM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=gKdQUKL7IYmo8QS53oHICw&ved=0CE4Q9QEwBQ&dur=4097)). Because the precision decay and the recall grow as the TOP-K grows are important results to these systems.

But if you still want a better answer about the precision-recal versus ROC curves, read this [paper](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CGcQFjAG&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.cs.wisc.edu%2Fmachine-learning%2Fshavlik-group%2Fdavis.icml06.pdf&ei=sKdQUKu9IYO09QTa7IHQDA&usg=AFQjCNHD-RluCCB0rAa2pu_ktnvd1W0vDA&sig2=iDXWTxyUFSwT3UZzDeXjsw)